# How to solder wires onto pins of an RFID chip?

Tags: soldering, rfid, nfc

I want to integrate a sensor with NXP's NHS3152 ([datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NHS3152.pdf)). To do this I have to solder the wires onto the pins of the RFID chip.

What tools should I buy to do this?
What is a good reference to learn how to do it?

[image: NHS3152 Dimensions]

Comment: Get a breakout board or Dip adapter board

Comment: @DKNguyen, and a normal soldering iron? will it work ever for a chip this small?

Comment: If the breakout board has extended pads it should. You might need hot air though due to the bottom pad if it has no center hole.

Comment: Hot air? - I am really new at this so am a bit lost.

Comment: This might be too challenging to do by hand. Usually machines would take care of this type of soldering job. If you place down the solder first, blow some constant hot air onto the pads where solder can be in a liquid state, you can place the entire package onto the board all at once.

Comment: Ok, 
do you have a recommended soldering machine- hot air thing? 
how much do the machines cost, that could be a solution

Comment: I think you can do it by hand, it will just be very difficult. Any hair dryer that can reach above 450°C to liquefy the solder will be okay to use. I would go with @DKNguyen's advice one possibly using some type of adapter or premade board.

Comment: Good hot air machines can be very expensive and I don't know how reliable the cheap ones are. Just use an iron and something like this https://www.artekit.eu/products/breakout-boards/bbadapters/qfn-to-dip/qfn-24-5x5-p0-65-to-dip-adapter-pack-of-2/ Note the hole in the center pad and extended pads around the edge for hand soldering. Use liquid flux

Comment: The "proper" way to solder this is in a reflow oven, which is Not Cheap™. Unless you're doing this for a company and you can convince your boss to spend a few thousand on a reflow oven, I recommend trying to do it by hand or with a hot-air gun. You can also jury-rig a (bad, but serviceable) reflow oven out of a toaster oven and some additional electronics, if you think that's worth it.

Comment: Its for a University research project, so i have a bit of a budget. I found this one on amazon for 260 euros, i might open a new question on how too choose a reflow oven!.  https://www.amazon.it/BuoQua-Rifusione-180x235mm-Soldering-Automatico/dp/B072LYJF56/ref=asc_df_B072LYJF56/?tag=googshopit-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=313980288871&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3512615337359230063&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=20566&hvtargid=pla-685801899537&psc=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buy the $50 **NHS3152DBUL** evaluation board (Available from Digikey, Mouser, Arrow etc.) and you won't have to worry about soldering a leadless package or BGA by hand for your prototyping.

There's also a NHS3152TEMOADKUL starter kit for ~4dB more.

Comment: Comparing prices using dB is certainly a new thing to me! I like it.

Comment: @Hearth Remember to use 10*log(x), not 20, because money is power.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks! I am alreaedy in the process of purchasing them (Uni bureocracy can be slow). However once i have veryfied that sensor + chip funcitons correctly, i need to solder for a POC device.

Comment: I've done this by hand using hot air and stencil printed solder paste, but an oven is better. Or get someone with the proper equipment and skill set to just solder that chip down to the board and do the rest yourself.

Comment: Oven is best, but I for one could absolutely do this by hand.  You just need to find somebody with experience.  Are there any PCB assembly houses nearby?  They'd have a room full of techs who could do this for you.

Comment: @KyleB no idea, I'll search for PCB assembly houses- (I am in BOLOGNA) - Thanks!

Comment: @leoelectrics Not sure about PCBA houses, but I'll never forget visiting the fancy delis there- the tortellinis were priced per piece (and worth it).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend avoiding the RFID application especially elaborate soldering. But it will be in your flock to do a trial without making a specific Investment. You will need at least a USB microscope to do manual soldering. If you can find a suitable steel screen for your sheath, you can apply it to your pcb with cream solder. I'll explain at length if you want.
But the main thing is; While all RF products transmit the desired power through the antenna, a part of it will be reflected back to your circuit, which is called SWR, depending on factors such as path thickness and length (line impedance). This will depend on your factors such as solder quality and impedance. The permissible limits must be found in your datasheets.

I had previously soldered an RFID chip of the nxp by hand in one of my projects (under a microscope) I did all the necessary tests and it worked. But after a while they were all burned out one by one.
Although I went through my entire design, I couldn't find an error. When we started production at the prototype stage, we had all our cards arranged in professional typesetting machines, after washing in private bathrooms, the design has been working in the field under very difficult conditions for more than a year without any fault.

The reason for my long patch was to prevent friends who would deal with RF from wasting time by making wrong choices. Sorry for my long answer.

Comment: Great, 
i have a microscope, but you said that your chips eventually burned out, even in my case by just soldeing an antenna and my sensor will this happen? or were you doing something particular?