# How should I make an ECAD schematic for my RFID chip?

Tags: transistors, pcb, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, rfid

I want to integrate a sensor component with an RFID chip.
From the answers I have from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503872/how-to-solder-wires-onto-pins-of-an-rfid-chip/503888?noredirect=1#comment1289692_503888). I decided I need to contact a PCBA house. I need to draw an ECAD schematic for the PCBA house (**never done this before**) .
These are the components:

- RFID Chip;  ([Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SL3S1203_1213.pdf?))
- Sensor (TFT transistor)
- Capacitor

I want to connect a 1uF capacitor between VGS of the Transistor. Connect Source and Drain to VDD, VOUT. And Connect the antenna to the antenna pads.
Below is how i think i should draw the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA4M2l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How should i make an ECAD schematic so that it is clear to the PCBA house what i am looking to do?
What is the correct way of making the ECAD shematic so that it is clear to the PCBA house what I am looking to do ?

**EDIT From Voltage Spike's answer**:

I have modified the schematic so that it matches FIgure 3: pin configuration for SOT886 (from datsheet of RFID SLES1203_1213). I have connected the transitor, Capacitor, and antenna. At this point would it be clear for a PCBA house what i am askinf for ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Lgnh.png)</sup>

Comment: PCBA manufacturer’s won’t care what you tell them. They’ll make whatever you tell them and they won’t question it. However, it is up to you to make a proper design so that this can work properly. You can either design it yourself or contract a design. Either way, you’ll have to come up with some target specifications for a proper design. Read all of the datasheets and application notes, makes a schematic, come up with some type of layout, gerber, and BOM, and send it to the PCBA house. It wouldn’t hurt to ask what they need from you.

Comment: @leoelectrics The symbol is a nchannel mosfet. Some board houses also have engineers that can help you achieve your design results (at a cost of course)

Comment: @KingDuken, for now there is nothing else to add from the design, it is just connecting the capacitor, sensor and antenna as i show in the picture. What i am trying to find out is if the Circuit diagram i made is the correct/standard way of representing the RFID chip SLES1203_1213, as well as the other parts.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, there are no TFT transitors? you mean in schematics right? I chose the nchannel mosfet as there was no symbol for TFT transitor.

Comment: @leo they usually just call them mosfets, it's more about the way they operate. What is the part number for the "TFT"?

Comment: @VoltageSpike No part number, I am fabricating the Transitor. Here is the paper of the device i'm trying to replicate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326074118_Passive_radiofrequency_x-ray_dosimeter_tag_based_on_flexible_radiation-sensitive_oxide_field-effect_transistor

Comment: @leoelectrics The paper says they fabricated the transistor with a CMOS technology on polyethylene naphthalate, building a transistor like this would probably cost tens of thousands of dollars. And you would have to find a commercial fabricator than can work with the materials provided in the paper. Not too many people on this site have made custom transistors, I never have because even for a commercial business, this is cost prohibitive.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, yeah it's not cheap :). I'm a researcher in Materials Physics at a Uni. We make the transitors in portugal in a Clean room facility

Comment: @leoelectrics Ah, if you have the transistors, then all you need to do is package them and then throw them on a PCB with the SL3S1203, which is way easier than fabricating a transistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's on a PCB and all the components have pads, then usually a few files are generated with the component positions, a bill of materials (BOM) and reference designators indicate where all the components need to be. This is a good article on all the [info to create a PCB](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/designing-pcbs-advanced-smd/all). If you use Eagle cad or ki cad then the software is free.

The information on how to enter the information for the [SL3S1203](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SL3S1203_1213.pdf) can be found here, and the footprint looks like this:
[image]

However, if the above schematic is a modification for another board, or a board that has been already built the board house needs explicit\very exact instructions on how to make a custom modification.

Usually, I do the modification my self, provide a schematic and a picture and give step by step instructions on how to mount the components on the module. The instructions should be exact.

Comment: Just to confirm: if i buy a  SL3S1203 chip, it comes in a packagage: SOT886. So when i send my design to the PCBA house i need to stick to the configuration in Figure 3? then if i senda a circuit diagram with the Capacitor/antenna/sensor connected to the right pins that should be enough for a PCBA house to understand what i need?

Comment: @leoelectrics No, the boardhouse will need files on how to build the PCB. The link above describes how to generate these files. The PCBA will build exactly what you tell them to, and they won't care if it will work or not. If you know your design works, then go through the process and draw it up. If your not sure if it will work or not, then find a consultant and they will be able to help you through the design process. If you are just starting, its probably best to find a consultant.

Comment: My first few designs didn't work and I had to go through several iterations, it can cost a few hundred dollars or more each time a design is fabricated so its best to get it right the first time and find someone that knows how to do this.

Comment: I am sure the design works as I am just reproducing previous work on this project (the paper i linked earlier). Ok thanks, i will have a read on how to generate these files.